# Send prompt after a default timer

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm working on Google Actions Console.

I want to have my google agent to verbally warn that time is up (instead of setting a timer, for instance).

I have now two main scenes:

1. user says "I am ready", the agent responds "OK. Ready, set, go!";
2. (user says nothing and) the agent says "please stop now".

I would like the prompt in 2 to proactively run 5 minutes after the end of the prompt in 1, without the user having to say anything.

Is it possible to create a timer/delay fo 5 min before the transition from 1 to 2 or to have the prompt in 2 delayed of 5 min during scene 2? How can I create this delay? Is there any workaround otherwise?

NB: I'm not a developer so be patient :D

Comment: @Calculuswhiz I am in google actions console and want to make what we could call a "voice-based timer", so instead of asking google assistant to set a timer, i want to have an agent that when the user says "i'm ready", the assistants says only "ok ready set go" without saying "i set a timer of 5 minutes" and that, after 5 minutes says "ok stop now" or "time is up". Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

This is difficult to do without code, but not impossible.

First - in general, Actions on Google is poorly suited for this. It is much better for conversational systems rather than timed events.

You have two options for how to do this:

1. As part of an Interactive Canvas game.
2. Using a Media response.

**As part of an Interactive Canvas game**

This scenario has you controlling the timer using JavaScript code that is part of an Interactive Canvas page that you have loaded on a Smart Display or Smart Phone device. As part of the "Ready Set Go" response, you send data back to indicate that your local code should start the timer.

You'll capture this data as part of the [`onUpdate()`](https://developers.google.com/assistant/interactivecanvas/reference#onupdate) callback and in your callback function set the timer. This timer is done using JavaScripts `setTimeout()` function.  In the function that `setTimeout()` triggers when it is done, you can call the [`sendTextQuery()`](https://developers.google.com/assistant/interactivecanvas/reference#sendtextquery) function to continue the conversation.

**Using a Media response**

This will work on devices that can play long-form audio, but do not have a screen (so they can't use the Interactive Canvas).

In this scenario, when you send the "Ready Set Go" response, you also include a [Media](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/prompts-media) prompt which plays a 5-minute long audio.

When the audio finishes playing, it will send a `MEDIA_STATUS_FINISHED` System Intent which you can handle and then reply to continue the conversation.

**Which should you use?**

Well... maybe both. Media works better on Smart Speakers, while the Interactive Canvas works better on Smart Displays and Smart Phones (assuming your Action is a Game).